# I want to divide/split screen of page after the menu or top bar

Tags: html, css

I want to divide the page after the top bar but it won't change. I want to design a page with three sections but the page also contains menu bar or head bar. I have tried something like below but it doesn't show anything at the top bar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .split {
      color: white;
      height: 80%;
      width: 30%;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .left {
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111;
    }
    
    .right {
      right: 0;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    #top {
      height: 20%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="top">
    <h2>Three Equal Columns</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="split left">
  </div>

  <div class="split right">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have used `position: fixed` and `top: 0` AND `z-index: 1` to **split** class which will automatically overlap **top** element. You can move the **split** class from top by 20% (`top: 20%`)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a fixed position concept like this in general, but apart from that you need to set `top: 20%` for the `.split` sections to leave space at the top for the top bar, plus you shouldn't use `color: white` on a white background, because text will remain invisible that way (white text on white background)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.split {
  height: 80%;
  width: 30%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

#top{
height:20%;
width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="top">
<h2>Three Equal Columns</h2>
</div>
<div class="split left">
</div>

<div class="split right">

</div>
     
</body>
</html>
```